# Get originating language code when using language fallback

Tags: multilingual, language-fallback

I have a component returning content from a set up fallback language, so far so good. Is there anyway for me to find out the originating language code for this? At the moment, everything I have tried gives me the language code for the current language.

So context language is Arabic, component fallbacks to English; how do I get the language code "en" through the API?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard without intellisense sometimes, here we go:

```
@Model.Item.OriginalLanguage.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName
```